# Getting minutes on a bootstrap calender

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a calendar using bootstrap. The user is able to pick a start date and the end date would be in the range of 7 days according to the start date.
The user is able to pick a hour, however i am having trouble, as i want the user to pick minutes as well.

I have been stuck on this for quite a while.

The code for the calender is :

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            $(function () {
                $('#startdate').datetimepicker({
minDate:today,
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
});
            });


$( "#start_dt" ).change(function() {
 var date_end = new Date($("#start_dt" ).val().replace(/-/g,"/"));
 var start_dt=date_end
 start_dt.setDate(start_dt.getDate());;
 start_dt=new Date(start_dt.getFullYear(), start_dt.getMonth(), start_dt.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
 date_end.setDate(date_end.getDate() + 6);
 date_end = new Date(date_end.getFullYear(), date_end.getMonth(), date_end.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
minDate:start_dt,
maxDate:date_end,
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
});
});
$( "#start_dt" ).blur(function() {
 var date_end = new Date($("#start_dt" ).val().replace(/-/g,"/"));
 var start_dt=date_end
 start_dt.setDate(start_dt.getDate());;
 start_dt=new Date(start_dt.getFullYear(), start_dt.getMonth(), start_dt.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
 date_end.setDate(date_end.getDate() + 6);
 date_end = new Date(date_end.getFullYear(), date_end.getMonth(), date_end.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
   minDate:start_dt,
maxDate:date_end,
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
});
});


        </script>
```

This is the html code

```
        <div>Start Date</div>
        <label for="startdate" class="sr-only">Start Date</label>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6' style="padding-left:0px">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='startdate'>
                        <input type='text' name="startdate" id="start_dt" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div>End Date (Can only be 7 days from start date)</div>
<label for="enddate" class="sr-only">End Date </label>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6' style="padding-left:0px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='enddate'>
                    <input type='text' name="enddate"  id="end_dt" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Double check your format string -- case matters.

Comment: Try changing your date format string to `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to amend your [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) string

```
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
});
```

But this will also include a seconds picker. If this is undesireable you'll need to drop seconds from the format.

```
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
});
```

Of course this will remove seconds from the display.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45qycz8t/1/) example.